# Понятие понятия "Понятие"

Tags: лексика

Может ли понятие быть не только существительным, но и, например, инфинитивом или наречием?

Понятие "Быть собой" крайне растяжимое.
Много — это такое понятие, настоящая степень которого не определена.

Comment: Что есть понятие? Это обозначенные словами существенные признаки объекта. Понятие предлагает систему признаков, оно объективно. Отождествлять понятие (науч.) и понимание/представление (инд.) не следует. Понятие определённо и не растяжимо.

Comment: Растяжимость — это ведь возможность различной трактовки. Допустим, мы имеем дело с родо-видовыми отношениями понятий. Если понятие более общее (род), оно может быть применено в отношении разных менее общих понятий, входящих в него (вид). Родовые понятия, таким образом, растяжимы.

Answer (score 2):

Понятие – **неоднозначное** слово.  В науке это точное определение  предметов и явлений по их существенным признакам, но есть и другое значение – представление, понимание или даже мнение.  Существует  разговорный речевой вариант – «понятия не имею».

Поэтому приведенные высказывания вполне корректны: Понятие «быть собой» крайне растяжимое. Много — это такое понятие, настоящая степень которого не определена.

Из словаря

**ПОНЯТИЕ**, ср. 1. Мысль, отражающая **существенные** свойства и необходимые признаки предмета или явления. П. времени. П. качества. П. треугольника. Понятия науки.  2. только ед. **Представление** о чём-л.; знание, **понимание** чего-л. Дать основное п. стоимости. Получить некоторое п. о предмете. // Разг. **Мнение** о ком-, чём-л., оценка кого-, чего-л. Составить себе п. о ком-л.

Comment: И так люди говорят?

Comment: Прочитайте комментарий shampar ("**Отождествлять понятие (науч.) и понимание/представление (инд.) не следует.**"). А надо так: *Я без понятия, что значит "быть собой". Понятие о том, что такое "много".*

Comment: Вы обратили внимание на минусы (моего там нет)? Значит, люди возмущаются, как такое вообще можно пытаться сделать.

Comment: Людям, вероятно,  не нравится заголовок, а по сути вопрос понятный. Слово "понятие" часто используется в самых разных ситуациях. И почему мне не отождествлять понятие и понимание, если в словаре это соответствует второму значению слова. А люди что только не говорят! Запросто могут кому-то сказать, что он не в теме и без понятия.

Comment: Только что обратил внимание на заголовок. Очень оригинально. *что он не в теме и без понятия* — это да (*без понимания*). Но не *понятие "много"*. Может ещё союз приплетём? *Понятие "к тому же" означает следующее...* "Понятие" — это аналог слова "термин", но оно не такое строгое и научное.

Comment: Всё дело в тире (рассуждать о значении слов и отождествлять — вещи разные).  В одном примере — это лишь слово, не определяющее настоящую степень и т. д.,, а в другом — словосочетание, никак не мнение или представление. Некий девиз, позиция, и только.

Comment: @Sharon Не улавливаю логику вашего вывода. "Поэтому приведенные высказывания вполне корректны" — *Понимание/представление «быть собой» крайне растяжимое? Много — это такое понимание/представление, настоящая степень которого не определена?*

Comment: Есть понятие (чего-либо) - это научный термин. Но есть еще понятие  о чем-либо  (второе значение слова). Если сочетание имеет словарное определение, то мы говорим: понятие "много", понятие  "быть собой". Если такого определения нет,  то мы говорим понятие о чем, например, понятие об основах композиции (это целая тема).

Comment: *Есть понятие (чего-либо)* — только о существительном. Не употребляется оно в других случаях. Какую замену (не значение) из словаря (синоним) вы туда подставите?

Answer (score 0):

Нет, так не говорят. Режет слух.

Словарь Кузнецова
понятие
1) Логически оформленная общая мысль о классе **предметов, явлений**, идея чего-л.
*Понятие времени.

Понятие качества.

Понятия науки.

Отражение понятий в словах.*

Словарь Ушакова
понятие
1. Логически расчлененная общая мысль о **предмете**, включающая ряд взаимносвязанных признаков.
*Определение понятия.

Понятие квадрата. Понятие прибавочной стоимости.

Содержание понятия.

Противоречащие друг другу понятия.*

Comment: *Нет, так не говорят.* — Могу предположить, что Вы предпочитаете художественную литературу научно-популярной. И ещё могу уверенно сказать, что Вы снова не попробовали проверить на прочность свои категорические утверждения хотя бы поиском по Нацкорпусу.

Comment: Давайте примеры, это поможет разобраться.

Comment: Нет, это не поможет разобраться. Единственное, что действительно может помочь в таком случае разобраться, это попытаться найти эти примеры самостоятельно. Вы умеете пользоваться формой "Лексико-грамматический поиск"? Если нет, я помогу простыми советами.

Comment: А по поводу предпочтений я угадал, не так ли?

Comment: Зачем мне искать абсурдные вещи? Если бы примеры были, вы бы уже давно их привели. Нет, не угадали, читаю только новости. Но выбрал бы научную. Даже и не знаю (для одного слова должно получиться), но точно не умею вот что. Как там найти два слова, между которыми есть любое количество слов (не только соседние)? Умеет ли оно искать по всем падежам, а не только заданный?

Comment: @grizzly Подскажите, пожалуйста, как там обозначить начало предложения? Не подскажите ещё, почему этот поиск не работает и как сделать, чтоб он заработал? https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexgramm&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=Как&gramm1=&sem1=&flags1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=20&lex2=так+и&gramm2=&sem2=&flags2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2

Answer (score 0):

Второй ответ (на комментарии)

Слово «понятие»  можно использовать в соответствии **со словарной статьей** для него.

1. Все слова и фразеологические сочетания являются **понятиями**, если можно найти для них общепринятое **определение**.

"Быть самим собой" – это **понятие**, так как устойчивое выражение имеет определенное  значение: держаться естественно, вести себя сообразно своим свойствам, особенностям. [https://kartaslov.ru/значение-слова/быть+самим+собой](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BC+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9)

2. Если такое определение найти нельзя,  то словосочетание  можно считать **понятием о чем-то**. Так, композиция – это **понятие**, в словаре у него три значения. Основы композиции – это уж **понятие о чем-то**, если вы в этом разбираетесь.
3. А если не очень разбираетесь  – то у вас всего лишь **представление** или **мнение.** (Интересно об этом подумать, когда мы пишем ответы на форуме.)

Comment: *Все слова и фразеологические сочетания являются понятиями* — мне так не кажется.

Comment: Кажется - это мнение, да?  Может быть, и о представлении тоже расскажете (почему вам так кажется).

Comment: Так люди не говорят. Режет слух.